# Setting timing in javascript. any idea for widget?

Tags: html

i want to give user facility to choose  how much time from the datepicker . they can choose in 
minutes and hours.

are their any datepicker can help me to choose the timespan or timestamp.

any way to do this in html5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In html5 you can pick timestamp using one of following inputs:

```
<input type="date">
<input type="month">
<input type="week">
<input type="time">
<input type="datetime">
<input type="datetime-local">
```